# jQuery toggle slider bar

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 as my framework and i want to create a fixed slide bar at the top right of my page on my background image for extra information. But the problem is whenever i click the jquery triggered button i fixed on-top, the contents are displayed on the bottom of the background image instead of sliding on the background image itself with z-index higher. This is what i am trying to achieve you can see it on this template,the red slider button on top:

http://demo.themetorium.net/html/asso/v.1.3/theme/index.html

[This is my jsFiddle so far](https://jsfiddle.net/s0qqrz7r/39/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider-button p").click(function(){

        $(".top-slider").slideToggle();
        $(".hey").css('right', '0');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi can you make a fiddle for better understanding

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: let me amend my question again.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s0qqrz7r/39/

Comment: Is there a jquery plugin that does exactly this for me?

Comment: Just like the link i presented on my parent question in the begining.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a plugin, just do the same thing the fiddle you provided in comments does ([the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0qqrz7r/39)).

Alternatively you can put a classical navbar with transparent background with a similar way to [collapsed navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#external-content)

```
<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Then in css

```
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This might do the trick ?

Comment: yes,but i want the collapse menu to expand over the contents given a bigger z-index,not push the contents downwards while it toggles.